# blank page with iis7 when using .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, iis-7

i am having strange problem, when i change the default app pool to use .Net 4.0 from .Net 2.0 i get blank page with no HTML, strangely enough i have VS 2010 installed with Net4.0

thanks in adavanced

Comment: This happens when you've deployed this application to a server?

Comment: no 
just locally, if i use cassini it works fine, just iis

Comment: can i know why i got down voted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirm that your project is targeting the .NET Framework 4. You'd expect a non-blankpage with some description, but just making sure. Perhaps your browser is showing 'friendly' errors?

Check in the Event Viewer for any .NET or IIS related error messages. There likely will be some clues there as to what's going on.

Consider creating a brand new website in IIS to test out your app deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the <handlers> section in your web.config. Do the <add> tags have this attribute?

```
preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv2.0"
```

Try removing the part after "integratedMode". The preconditions prevents them from being used in .NET 4.0. Without any usable handlers, you won't see a response.